# Add markers and hyperlinks for citations in pandoc

Tags: pdf-generation, latex, pandoc

I put references in a yaml metadata-header:

```
references:
- id: fenner2012a
  title: One-click science marketing
  author:
  - family: Fenner
    given: Martin
  ...
```

(described here: http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#extension-citations)

and I can cite this reference with `See [@fenner2012a]...`.

This will create an output in the pdf like this: `See ("One-click science marketing")...` with no hyperlink on the reference.

Instead of the title I want to have auto-incremented number: `See [1]` with [1] being a hyperlink to the source. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems better suited for http://tex.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @DaveJarvis [tag:latex] is merely one output format of [tag:pandoc], so unless the only acceptable answer involves modifying the latex-template and not either additional yaml-header information, a custom filter or even modifying the pandoc source itself (in [tag:haskell]) I beg to differ

Comment: @macrozone Have you tried `pandoc --natbib` or `pandoc --biblatex` as mentioned in that manual? Or a customized LaTeX-[template](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates)? https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref might also be worth looking at

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of the title I want to have auto-incremented number: `See [1]` with [1](https://www.zotero.org/styles?format=numeric) being a hyperlink to the source. How can I achieve this?

Many CSL styles have a [numeric format](https://www.zotero.org/styles?format=numeric); you can try [ACM Computing Surveys](https://www.zotero.org/styles/computing-surveys).

To specify the style, [pandoc's documentation says](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL%202.html#specifying-a-citation-style):

> These files are specified using the `--csl` option or the `csl` (or citation-style) metadata field.

<del>There's one caveat when going to PDF, however. **I haven't found a way to get the hyperlinking to work**.
That is, you'll get `See [1]` but there is no hyperlink.</del>
Edit: You can get this to work by using the following setting in meta-data:

```yaml
link-citations: true
```

You can get hyperlinks in PDF by using LaTeX's way of formatting references. But I think you'll have to convert your reference to `.bib` format and specify it in your metadata:

```yaml
bibliography: references.bib

  pdf:
    cite-method: biblatex
```