# Add hyperlinks for citations (figures, sections) by using pandoc and markdown to generate pdfs

Tags: pdf, latex, markdown, pandoc

I would like to generate academic paper from markdown using pandoc. Everything goes perfectly except the hyperlink for cross-references:

I just used this to generate pdf: `pandoc xxx.md -o xxx.pdf --biliography=path\bib.bib`, and wrote `@author2015` in the .md file for a citation.

In the output pdf-file, all the references are listed in the bibliography, and the citation looks like `(author, 2015)` , but without being a hyperlink into the bibliography. Similar question without answer here: [Add markers and hyperlinks for citations in pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788027/add-markers-and-hyperlinks-for-citations-in-pandoc)

Similar problem occurred when I tried to generate a hyperlink to an internal section in the same document, by writing: `see [this](#shorttitle)` in markdown, to jump to a former section with a title like `## Title {#shorttitle}`.

Could anyone who is familiar with pandoc and markdown tell me, how can I fix this problem to generate those hyperlinks? Is this a limit of pandoc, or should I add some other configurations? Thank you!

Comment: Can you try the just released pandoc 1.15.2? changelog states "fixed internal links in LaTeX/PDF"

Comment: Thank you! After updating the pandoc it works..

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in Pandoc 1.15.2, the [announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/D49s_Dw4TYY) states "fixed internal links in LaTeX/PDF".